# What are the meanings of the common verbs we use to mean change?

Tags: meaning, verbs, word-usage

Having acknowledged that the meanings of these verbs overlap, how would describe the prototypical use of each of these verbs?

1. *Become*

   - It was becoming dark.
   - He became a pilot.
2. *Get*

   - It was getting dark.
   - You get older every day.
3. *Go*

   - She went white with rage.
   - The milk will go sour.
4. *Come*

   - I came to realize it was the best thing to do.
   - My predictions usually come true.
5. *Turn*

   - Bruce Banner turned into the hulk.
   - The traffic light will turn green soon.

Comment: Are you seeking to find some critical difference that calls for the use of one of them to the exclusion of others? Or are you looking for a common denominator meaning?

Comment: Even addressing the issues in respect of any *one* of these five verbs would be Too Broad.

Comment: @bib yes, the former.

Comment: @FumbleFingers get a life.

Comment: @Hal, please note from the FAQ that ELU is a site [for linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155001/) (which clearly doesn't include *you*). You should address questions like this to [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), and find some dorky chatroom where comments like that are perhaps more appropriate.

Comment: I think it's a great (multi-part) question, but as FF says, would need a doctoral thesis for a near-complete answer.

Comment: I like this question and I would like a thorough answer even more... but as it is, it is a little awe inducing. It really is broad, how about picking out two or three verbs and moving on from there?

Answer (score 1):

The overlap is huge. While not every single one of the words you list can be used in every circumstances, most can

> *Became*
>
> It was becoming dark.
>
> He became a pilot.
>
> You become older every day.
>
> She became white with rage.
>
> My predictions usually become true.
>
> Bruce Banner became the hulk.
>
> *Get*
>
> He got to be a pilot.
>
> It was getting dark.
>
> You get older every day.
>
> She got white with rage.
>
> The milk got sour.
>
> *Go*
>
> It goes dark.
>
> She went white with rage.
>
> The milk will go sour.
>
> The traffic light will go green soon.
>
> *Came*
>
> I came to realize it was the best thing to do.
>
> My predictions usually come true.
>
> It came to be dark.
>
> *Turn*
>
> It turned dark.
>
> He turned into a pilot.
>
> You turn older every day.
>
> She turned white with rage.
>
> The milk will turn sour.
>
> My predictions usually turn true.
>
> Bruce Banner turned into the hulk.
>
> The traffic light will turn green soon.

While some of these choices flow better than others, there is not a bright line distinction as to what makes one appropriate and another not.

Answer (score 0):

These seems to work.

- *Get*
  Ascribes a state to a noun.
- *Become*
  Denotes gradual change or addition of salient enduring characteristics; the change is not effected by any external sentient entity.
- *Come*
  Ascribes an adjective to the subject; stresses a result more than a process; the change affects non-enduring properties; the change was not effected by the changed entity's will. Used only when commenting on the past, or the predicted past relative to some predicted future deixis
- *Go*
  Ascribes an adjective to the subject; used to denote a change in state; the change is not effected by any external entity.
- *Turn*
  Denotes a complete change of the relevant property; change happens quickly; not intentional unless accompanied by a reflexive.